# How can I install IIS without the Windows XP CD?

Tags: windows-xp, iis

I've bought a refurbished machine from Dell with Windows XP Professional SP3.  I want to install IIS to practice with ASP.NET.  To install I'm prompted to insert a CD I don't have.

There are methods explained (via Google) involving locating and finding an i386 file that has been unsuccessful.

I'm prepared to start over from scratch to get IIS installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of anyway to just install IIS without the CD or any XP resources.

That being said, If this is just for practice, take a look at [Cassini Personal Web Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2005/09/27/474534.aspx). You can find out [more information about it on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltiDev_Cassini_Web_Server).

This is basically the source code and the component of Visual Studio that serves up ASP.Net content (when you choose not to target IIS).

It is fully featured and fully working web server for development.

It may not have all the features of IIS, but IIS is restricted on XP anyway and this should do everything and anything you need.

Otherwise, feel free to install either [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/default.aspx) or just [Visual Studio Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/) which can do the same.

Comment: Thank you Wil.  I've opted for Visual Web Developer Express Ed. 2008 through your last link.  I'll go forward with my ASP.NET tutorial and drop any comments here in case it helps others.

Comment: Nice answer!  You covered it all.